# Delete all rows before range and after range

Tags: excel, vba

community!

I write the code that finds Range.Address. Between the two ranges is the table I need. Now my task is: a) Delete all rows before the first range b) delete all rows after the second range
The code itself looks like this:

```
Sub FindCellAddressByString()

Dim rngA As Range
Dim rngB As Range
Set rngA = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(Cells.Address).Find("Transit goods to England", lookat:=xlPart)
Set rngB = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(Cells.Address).Find("TOTAL:", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngA Is Nothing And Not rngB Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox rngA.Address & " " & rngB.Address
End If

End Sub
```

Please tell me how do I delete all the rows starting from the startRow and ending with the rngA row? After that, me need to delete all rows starting from rngB and ending with the final row (endRow). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub FindCellAddressByString()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim rngB As Range

    Set rngA = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(Cells.Address).Find("Transit goods to England", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set rngB = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range(Cells.Address).Find("TOTAL:", lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not rngA Is Nothing And Not rngB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rngA.Address & " " & rngB.Address
    End If

    Rows(rngB.Row + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
    Rows(1 & ":" & rngA.Row - 1).Delete
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Note the **+-** in the `Delete` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very grateful to you!